# Calling Entrust API from C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any library, API or whatever way to call Entrust API from .NET?

I tried looking for a library but there's only a library for Java. Is there a way to use the Java library in a .NET application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is, or so I was told once, but it is unofficial and largely junk (again, so I heard). Entrust itself certainly appears to not have such a thing; their tools aren't exactly programmer friendly a lot of the time. We're a .NET shop too and had to basically build external utilities to call the ETKforJ with external processes, etc.